# Point estimates scale skewed

Tags: agile, scrum, planning, estimation

When using planning poker for estimates, we've ended up with effectively a non-linear points scale. By that I mean that point value is inconsistent for one-pointers and, say, eight-pointers. Couple examples each:

- 1 point: add tooltip text to a couple of icons; format date&time strings
- 3 points: create new user role and specify their permissions; automatically create a new case in CRM whenever certain actions are performed
- 5 points: watchlist functionality; filtering functionality on several facets
- 8 points: integrate with a third party provider *and* introduce a persistence layer to cache their responses

My concern is two-fold: we lose estimating fidelity by restricting ourselves to the low-end of the scale and any reporting (or calculating average velocity) will be erroneous.

How can I entice the scrum master, product owner and the team to use a more consistent, linear scale?

**Edit:** just to clarify, we are using [one of the traditional decks](http://store.mountaingoatsoftware.com/products/planning-poker-cards) that goes all the way up to 100... except we've somehow anchored ourselves to not go over 5, ending up with effectively a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Related on ProjectManagement.SE: [Why do Scrum user stories only use the Fibonacci series?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/9851/4469) and [Why would teams use the Fibonnacci sequence for story points?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/4251/4469) - and then there's the entire [story points](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-points) tag to read... reading this and those questions, you might want to consider that you don't have *enough* options to use as point values.

Comment: @MichaelT: I've added a clarification to the question - we certainly have enough options to use as point values, but we've ended up biased against a big chunk of the effective range. +1 for link to  ProjectManagement.SE!

Comment: I would love to provide an answer except I disagree with your implicit premise that a linear progression is a good thing. As the answers stated in @MichaelT's links, higher numbers have more uncertainty. The distances between numbers have to increase along with the numbers themselves. So I reject the null hypothesis and stick with something vaguely Fibonnacci-like.

Comment: What actual problems are you encountering by using this non-linear scale? Do you get wildly differing sprint velocities depending on the ratio between 1-point stories and 5/8-point stories?

Comment: It sounds like your team is hesitant to assign higher point values to stories that need them. The problem with your example estimation is that the last few, especially the one assigned 8 points, should probably have been assigned 20 or 40 points, and then broken down into more reasonable chunks for re-estimating.

Comment: I would also note that your 1 point story we would have scored 0.  It has a trivial effort and adds no new functionality(unless you have to create a new tooltip functionality but then its probably more than 1).

Comment: @EricKing I don't think this is the case.  Our team has also ended up with the same logarithmic scale over time (such that an 8-point case is _way_ larger than three 3-point cases).  It's not all that surprising, either, given that [humans apparently think logarithmically and not linearly](http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2012/thinking-logarithmically-1005)

Comment: @Izkata My point is that an 8-point case should not be *way larger* than a 3-point case. If the case is really that much larger, it should be a 20-pointer. But, there seems to be something keeping the team from choosing the more realistic choice. Is there some stigma against the larger numbers? Fix that problem, and the skewing will go away.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I entice the scrum master, product owner and the team to use a
>   more consistent, linear scale?

**You shouldn't need to convince them**. Reviewing inaccurate point estimates should be part of your retrospective. If any stories ended up being more complicated than anticipated, make note of it.

> We only estimated 8 points on STR-1234; but it was
>   definitely more than 8 time as complex as a typical 1 point story. I'd say it was more like
>   *13 times* as complex. Possibly even in the 21 point range.

At that point, you'll *ideally* have a conversation about whether the estimate could have been better with more time to discuss the story, whether it was high enough that it should have been given a *huge* estimate until being broken down into smaller stories, or whether the bad estimate was unavoidable -- and maybe whether it should have been replaced with (or converted to) a spike during the sprint.

If you can, transition into that conversation without "convincing" anyone that points are informative and useful when done right; you just need to keep up the practice of discussing bad estimates at each review.

**If you're SCRUM implementation is broken**, you may get pushback.

> But, it took the same amount of time as your other 8 pointers!

Or whatever.

At that point, if it occurs, you need to start a discussion about *Why you're attempting to use a SCRUM process* and *Why successful SCRUM implementations work*. That discussion can take months. But, it starts by asking your coworkers and boss what they expect out of the process.

At the very least, to address the question at hand, **ask the product owner and team what they expect out of story point estimates**. Ask them things like:

- Should they ensure that each sprint can be treated like a commitment?
- Should they ensure we don't spend too much time on minimally valuable improvements?
- Should they help the product owner determine if X can be done N sprints from now?

The correct answer to all of the above is *yes*, of course. And to achieve any of the benefits, you need a meaningful velocity data.  If `8 != 1 * 8` in your reports, the data is meaningless.

Comment: I like your last sentence :)

Comment: @svidgen: the problem with reviewing the estimates in a retro is that they actually *fit* our scale. It's just that the scale is non-linear - an eight-pointer above is much more than eight times as complex as a one-pointer.

Comment: @o.v. You've explicitly agreed in the past that the scale should be non-linear?

Comment: @svidgen: no. When this inconsistency *(an eight-pointer... more than eight times as complex as a one-pointer)* was flagged up in one of the retros, the product owner's reply was "well, that's the way it is" ;_;

Comment: @o.v. The way *what* is? ... It sounds like you need start the "why are we doing SCRUM?" and/or "what are our story point estimates good for?" conversations. Your "product owner" doesn't seem to fully understand what the point of the disciplines are. ... I mean hell, why is the PO telling *you* why a story is scored the way it is!?? It's *your* job to tell *him* how big it is; his job is pretty exclusively one or prioritization.

Comment: @svidgen: hmm, perhaps this would be a good subject for a "pre-retro". You're right, I don't think this is a subject the PO should even be exposed to.

Comment: @o.v. I'm not sure what you mean. The PO needs to see the points for planning and promising purposes. But, he should have readonly privileges on those estimates! And its in his *and the team's* best interest to ensure that 8 is roughly 1 * 8. Else, how do you know what an average velocity of ... I dunno ... 32 means? Is that 32 1 point stories? Is it 4 8-point stories? Or is it only meaningful if you have a sprint of 16 1-pointers and 2 8-pointers?

Comment: @svidgen: imho reporting activities go on top of the "foundation" of dev estimates - since I expect the PO to push back on adjusting the scale, I'd rather get backing for the issue with the dev team & scrum master first and then present it to the PO as "this is something we need for our dev processes to work, and by the way this will contribute to meaningful reporting"

Comment: @svidgen We also ended up with a logarithmic scale, and balance it out by pulling in around the same number of cases of each point level in each sprint.  This way the sprints stay comparable and velocity consistent despite the points not adding up linearly between cases.  There's nothing wrong with a logarithmic scale as long as it's adjusted for in other ways.

Comment: yes there is something wrong with a logarithmic scale because it forces you to compromise your planning just to get things to almost work.

Answer (score 2):

For me there is nothing wrong with the fibunacci scale, from what I read and see as examples the problem lies more in the estimates, or the way you estimate.

I do not know the exact situation that you are in, but there seems to be an imbalance between the estimates on the lower ends and the estimates on the higher ends. 8 times a task like adding tooltip text to a couple of icons do not seem to match integrating with integrating 3rd party software and caching the responses.

I know it is not good to compare story points to man days, but I usually seek for a story that will take the developers about 1 day of work, everything included. I don't tell them that I think it is about 1 day of work, I want to avoid that they compare the points to days. This will be our reference story that gets 2 story points. If another story is only half the work, it will be a 1, if another story is small enough, it might be a 1/2. We pick a good 2 story points story that allows us to go small enough. For bigger stories we always compare them with the reference story and stories that have already been found with a higher number. I see in my team that it helps to have some good reference stories lying on the table with a 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 story point estimate. Humans are much better at comparing that at measuring.

We also avoid going to big as you do. The limit is often set to 8 SP's. The team is allowed to go above the 8 SP in the original estimates, but this almost always results in splitting it up into smaller parts and estimating these parts again.

No one stops you from using a 4 or a 6 or even a 10 if you feel that the team is not confortable of using the fibonacci numbers for a certain story. We do it also from time to time. We do avoid to do this to often.

And yes, sometimes your estimates are wrong. It happens to every team. But the law of the big numbers tells me that if I estimate 10 stories to be an 8, statistically these stories are on average an 8.

For your 8 SP story, I would recommend to first take away the uncertanty. I see a number of possibilities for this that can even be combined.

1. Split the story in an integration part and a caching part.
2. Clearly define cases to integrate in stead of trying to integrate every specific case at once.
3. Go for a timeboxed effort to get to know the third party soft better before estimating.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with using a non-linear story point scale is that it completely screws up Velocity calculations.

**In other words, it makes it hard to know how many story points (how much complexity) you can ship in a fixed-length sprint**.

Consider two sprints with different story point distributions, but the same total number of story points

```
Sprint 1 breakdown (16 points):
16 x 1 story point

Sprint 2 breakdown (16 points):
8 x 2 story points
```

With a linear estimation scale **and a steady velocity** (eg, 1 story point maps to 1 hour of work) both sprints a comparable amounts of work.  Both sprints will take roughly 16 hours and the story point estimates clearly indicate this.

However, if you use an exponential scale you get totally misleading results.

Let's assume your conversion scale is something like

```
n story points = n^2 hours
```

So sprint 1 turns out to be

```
16 x 1 story point =
16 x (1^2) hours =
16 * 1 hours
16 hours
```

Sprint 1, consisting of 16 story points, **is 16 hours long**.

Now let's consider sprint 2.

```
8 * 2 story points =
8 * (2^2) hours =
8 * 4 hours =
32 hours
```

So, sprint 2, consisting of 16 story points, is actually **32 hours long**.

This is **twice** as long as your first sprint because you're attempting to deliver **twice** the complexity.

Thus, the impact of using an exponential scale is that the number of story points in a fixed-length sprint doesn't actually represent the amount of complexity being delivered.

This will make calculating Velocity and using Burdown Charts very difficult.

That should be reason enough to your Scrum Master.

---

**Clarification**

The only reason I'm relating story points to time is because sprints have a fixed length in time.

Assuming your team has a fairly stable *real* velocity, estimating with a non-linear scale will make it so that two sprints of the same length in time with the same story point content being worked on at the same velocity are not actually comparable.

In other words, two sprints with the same total number of story points aren't actually shipping the same amount of complexity.

Comment: A soon as I read points=hours I shuddered.  We've learned that trying to do this is a big mistake.  It's ok to look back historically over time to see what points mean, and how stories *really* turned out, but to do it on an individual story and try to relate that story points to hours has not proven fruitful in the places where I have worked (several) that do Agile.  Worst of all it frequently becomes both a tool to 'beat' people with and something that focuses on the wrong thing.  Careful what you measure 'n all.  The focus here is sprints so that partly ameliorates this answer.

Comment: If added some additional explanation as to why I'm relating things to time.

Comment: I'm not advocating converting story points into hours.  I'm simply trying to show that if story points use an exponential scale then two sprints of equal length in *time* can't always hold the same number of story points.

Comment: @MetaFight: thank you, velocity calculation seems a big red flag for me. However our sprint planning is commitment-based, so it's common to hear *"our velocity for the last sprint was X points, but we will not be be able to do quite so much this sprint because we are pulling in a five-pointer"*

Comment: "This is twice as long as your first sprint because you're attempting to deliver twice the complexity." This process confuses me. If you're delivering twice the complexity in the second sprint, why did you estimate them with the same number of points? Points are supposed to reflect relative complexity. If your 1st sprint was estimated at 16 story points, and the 2nd was approximately twice as complex, it should have been estimated at 32 points. "n story points = n^2 hours" is where the problem begins. If you _must_ convert points to hours, it should be "n story points = n*2 hours"

Comment: In other words, what makes the story point scale 'non-linear' is not some points-to-hours conversion factor, but the fact that you have a non-linear progression of point values to choose from (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, etc.). A linear point system only differs in that you can choose from a different progression of values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Fibonacci sequence at several places and it has worked well.  The points are a rough estimatation and represent scale as much as a certain level.  I've found that choosing 5 or 8 for what is an estimate is better than trying to get the desired discussion and ultimately agreement on points when the votes are `5-5-8-5-5-5-8-5` rather than `5-5-9-6-5-6-9-5`

To address your concerns about "lose estimating fidelity" I would recommend not worrying about it.  Estimating for the future is best used when there has been a bvuild up of several months of activity.  A couple of sprints is not enough.

I recommend that your primary use of points be to:

#### Generate discussion of key points of the ticket when people disagree in their point scores.

Comment: Downvote without comment.  Sigh. I dislike those.

Comment: My problem with this answer is that the five and eight in the original example are highly nonlinear. Integrating with a 3rd party provider and caching their responses is probably not as easy as creating 8 tooltips. It's much more work than creating three users and their permissions.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: we've been through a dozen or so sprints by now. Alan Shutko phrased well the concern about lack of fidelity - there is just so many different task complexities between our 1 and 8, and we'll have to end up pigeon-holing them.